# Appium: Nokogiri giving load error while running test case

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, appium

I have upgraded Ruby version to 2.1.0 from Ruby 1.8.7 and installed all dependencies to run a sample Appium test case using Ruby. But I am facing an issue to load nokogiri while running a test case.

I am using
OS: Mac OS - 1.9.2
Ruby: 2.1.0
Appium: 1.2.0
Nokogiri: 1.6.3.1
This works fine on Ruby: 1.8.7.

Error:

```
Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `require': dlopen(/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.2.1.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/appium_lib-4.1.0/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/appium_lib-4.1.0/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/appium_lib-4.1.0/lib/appium_lib.rb:28:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/appium_lib-4.1.0/lib/appium_lib.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Documents/rslRuby/li_workspace/flagship_native_tests/UITestFramework/selenium/base/LI_framework.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/Documents/rslRuby/li_workspace/flagship_native_tests/UITestFramework/selenium/base/LI_framework.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from samle_tests/sign_in_test.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Fix 1:**

This usually happens when gems are linked wrong, i recommend trying to re-install ruby via rvm.

```
rvm reinstall 2.1
rvm use 2.1
```

Make sure all the gems are up to date by running(in your apps directory)

```
bundle install
```

**Possible Fix 2:**

Another common problem is to install rvm as a root user, if you've done this re install rvm.

You can uninstall rvm by running

```
rvm implode
```

Follow the steps on the website to [install rvm](http://rvm.io/rvm/install)